# ERROR: for odoo-13-docker-compose_odoo13_1 a bytes-like object is required, not 'str' in docker-compose up

Tags: docker, odoo

I have stumbled an error on my terminal regarding odoo installation via docker.

```
$ docker - compose up
```

Error log:

```
odoo-13-docker-compose_db_1 is up-to-date

Starting odoo-13-docker-compose_odoo13_1 …

ERROR: for odoo-13-docker-compose_odoo13_1 a bytes-like object is required, not ‘str’

ERROR: for odoo13 a bytes-like object is required, not ‘str’

Traceback (most recent call last):

File “/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/docker/api/client.py”, line 261, in _raise_for_status

response.raise_for_status()
File “/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/requests/models.py”, line 940, in raise_for_status

raise HTTPError(http_error_msg, response=self)
requests.exceptions.HTTPError: 500 Server Error: Internal Server Error for url: http+docker://localhost/v1.22/containers/349ba7cac8d4be0b9ade1a3dc7a03c5dd4323552068dd0af2a5f4a04e010dd0e/start

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):

File “/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/compose/service.py”, line 625, in start_container

container.start()
File “/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/compose/container.py”, line 241, in start

return self.client.start(self.id, **options)
File “/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/docker/utils/decorators.py”, line 19, in wrapped

return f(self, resource_id, *args, **kwargs)
File “/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/docker/api/container.py”, line 1095, in start

self._raise_for_status(res)
File “/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/docker/api/client.py”, line 263, in _raise_for_status

raise create_api_error_from_http_exception(e)
File “/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/docker/errors.py”, line 31, in create_api_error_from_http_exception

raise cls(e, response=response, explanation=explanation)
docker.errors.APIError: 500 Server Error: Internal Server Error (“b’driver failed programming external connectivity on endpoint odoo-13-docker-compose_odoo13_1 (b47b736966bdeb7583e8a4285bb118fb6c82e63d4c0de977e612d7a9686c88fd): Bind for 0.0.0.0:10013 failed: port is already allocated’”)

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):

    load_entry_point('docker-compose==1.25.0', 'console_scripts', 'docker-compose')()
File “/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/compose/cli/main.py”, line 72, in main

command()
File “/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/compose/cli/main.py”, line 128, in perform_command

handler(command, command_options)
File “/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/compose/cli/main.py”, line 1107, in up

to_attach = up(False)
File “/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/compose/cli/main.py”, line 1088, in up

return self.project.up(
File “/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/compose/project.py”, line 565, in up

results, errors = parallel.parallel_execute(
File “/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/compose/parallel.py”, line 112, in parallel_execute

raise error_to_reraise
File “/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/compose/parallel.py”, line 210, in producer

result = func(obj)
File “/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/compose/project.py”, line 548, in do

return service.execute_convergence_plan(
File “/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/compose/service.py”, line 567, in execute_convergence_plan

return self._execute_convergence_start(
File “/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/compose/service.py”, line 506, in _execute_convergence_start

_, errors = parallel_execute(
File “/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/compose/parallel.py”, line 112, in parallel_execute

raise error_to_reraise
File “/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/compose/parallel.py”, line 210, in producer

result = func(obj)

File “/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/compose/service.py”, line 508, in

    lambda c: self.start_container_if_stopped(c, attach_logs=not detached, quiet=True),
File “/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/compose/service.py”, line 620, in start_container_if_stopped

return self.start_container(container)
File “/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/compose/service.py”, line 627, in start_container

if "driver failed programming external connectivity" in ex.explanation:
TypeError: a bytes-like object is required, not ‘str’

Error in sys.excepthook:

Traceback (most recent call last):

File “/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/apport_python_hook.py”, line 153, in apport_excepthook

with os.fdopen(os.open(pr_filename,
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: ‘/var/crash/_usr_bin_docker-compose.1000.crash’

Original exception was:

Traceback (most recent call last):

File “/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/docker/api/client.py”, line 261, in _raise_for_status

response.raise_for_status()
File “/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/requests/models.py”, line 940, in raise_for_status

raise HTTPError(http_error_msg, response=self)
requests.exceptions.HTTPError: 500 Server Error: Internal Server Error for url: http+docker://localhost/v1.22/containers/349ba7cac8d4be0b9ade1a3dc7a03c5dd4323552068dd0af2a5f4a04e010dd0e/start

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):

File “/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/compose/service.py”, line 625, in start_container

container.start()
File “/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/compose/container.py”, line 241, in start

return self.client.start(self.id, **options)
File “/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/docker/utils/decorators.py”, line 19, in wrapped

return f(self, resource_id, *args, **kwargs)
File “/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/docker/api/container.py”, line 1095, in start

self._raise_for_status(res)
File “/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/docker/api/client.py”, line 263, in _raise_for_status

raise create_api_error_from_http_exception(e)
File “/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/docker/errors.py”, line 31, in create_api_error_from_http_exception

raise cls(e, response=response, explanation=explanation)
docker.errors.APIError: 500 Server Error: Internal Server Error (“b’driver failed programming external connectivity on endpoint odoo-13-docker-compose_odoo13_1 (b47b736966bdeb7583e8a4285bb118fb6c82e63d4c0de977e612d7a9686c88fd): Bind for 0.0.0.0:10013 failed: port is already allocated’”)

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):

File “/usr/bin/docker-compose”, line 11, in

    load_entry_point('docker-compose==1.25.0', 'console_scripts', 'docker-compose')()
File “/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/compose/cli/main.py”, line 72, in main

command()
File “/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/compose/cli/main.py”, line 128, in perform_command

handler(command, command_options)
File “/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/compose/cli/main.py”, line 1107, in up

to_attach = up(False)
File “/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/compose/cli/main.py”, line 1088, in up

return self.project.up(
File “/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/compose/project.py”, line 565, in up

results, errors = parallel.parallel_execute(
File “/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/compose/parallel.py”, line 112, in parallel_execute

raise error_to_reraise
File “/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/compose/parallel.py”, line 210, in producer

result = func(obj)
File “/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/compose/project.py”, line 548, in do

return service.execute_convergence_plan(
File “/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/compose/service.py”, line 567, in execute_convergence_plan

return self._execute_convergence_start(
File “/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/compose/service.py”, line 506, in _execute_convergence_start

_, errors = parallel_execute(
File “/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/compose/parallel.py”, line 112, in parallel_execute

raise error_to_reraise
File “/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/compose/parallel.py”, line 210, in producer

result = func(obj)

File “/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/compose/service.py”, line 508, in

    lambda c: self.start_container_if_stopped(c, attach_logs=not detached, quiet=True),
File “/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/compose/service.py”, line 620, in start_container_if_stopped

return self.start_container(container)
File “/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/compose/service.py”, line 627, in start_container

if "driver failed programming external connectivity" in ex.explanation:
TypeError: a bytes-like object is required, not ‘s
```

I'm trying to run the server, but I got this error can anyone tell me how to fix this?

Answer (score 0):

Could you please share the docker-compose.yaml file ?

Please check the [Odoo's docker-compose](https://hub.docker.com/_/odoo?tab=description&page=1&ordering=last_updated) examples part:

Comment: `odoo13:
    image: odoo:13
    # container_name: odoo13
    depends_on:
      - db
    ports:
      - "10013:8069"
    tty: true
    command: -- --dev=reload
#    command: odoo scaffold /mnt/extra-addons/test_module
    environment:
      - HOST=db
      - USER=odoo
      - PASSWORD=odoo
    volumes:
      - ./addons:/mnt/extra-addons
      - ./etc:/etc/odoo
    restart: always             # run as a service`